# Did the Mig 21 have differential stabilators to help the ailerons?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, aircraft-performance, military

The MiG 21 had all-moving tailplanes or stabilators. When rolling, did one stabilator pitch up and the other down to act as secondary ailerons and help the main ones on the wing?

Comment: This video should at 6.35 gives a good view of a roll - no tailplane activity. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uePIzbYI7BU

Comment: Spoiler alert - no, the stabilisers didn't pitch when rolling in the video.

Comment: "Spoiler alert - no, the stabilisers didn't pitch when rolling in the video"-because is 1 G rolling maneuver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**.

MiG-21 (any modification) didn't need it and didn't have it. With its low-aspect-ratio delta wing and most mass concentrated in the centre, it was agile enough with standard ailerons.

The elevator had a single hydraulic booster driving both halves of the stabiliser.

Differential stabiliser was used on MiG-21's successor, MiG-23. That one had no ailerons at all; it had full-span flaps on its swing wing instead. Roll was controlled by the spoilers and the differential stabiliser.